# Java using more memory than the allocated memory

Tags: java, memory

An Apache Tomcat (Atlassian Confluence) instance is started using the following Java options:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.awt.headless=true "
```

However I see that after starting up it quickly eats through most of the 1GB of memory that is available on my virtual server.

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 6082 root      19   0 1105m 760m  16m S  0.7 74.2   5:20.51 java
```

Shouldn't the overall consumed memory (heap + PermGen) stay under what is specified using -Xmx? One of the problems this is causing is that I cannot shutdown the server using the shutdown script since it tries to spawn a JVM with 256MB of memory which fails because of it not being available.

Comment: Maybe there's some native memory allocation going on via JNI or `ByteBuffer`s with direct allocation.

Comment: @Steve Tayor Maybe... I don't know Confluence that well to know if it is doing that. I've posted a question on the Confluence forum but no answers yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Total Tomcat memory consumption should be calculated at NO LESS THAN `Xmx + XX:MaxPermSize` (in your case, 768MB), but I do recall seeing somewhere that it can go over that. `Xmx` is only the heap space, and `PermGen` is outside the heap (kind of).

Comment: heap + permgen + jvm overhead (unspecified amount)

Comment: @Wesho: Well, it could run in 512MB, you just need to adjust all your settings down accordingly. Perhaps `Xms256m, XX:MaxPermSize=128m` would do it.

Answer (score 5):

For example, a native library can easily allocate memory outside Java heap.

Direct ByteBuffer also does that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html

> The contents of direct buffers may
>   reside outside of the normal
>   garbage-collected heap, and so their
>   impact upon the memory footprint of an
>   application might not be obvious.

There are good reasons to allocate huge direct ByteBuffers.

http://ehcache.org/documentation/offheap_store.html