# How to Limit the kafka server Memory?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, jvm-arguments

I want to set the Max and minimum memory value for the Kafka server [9092 port]

Let say Max value is 2 GB, then memory usage should not exceeds the 2GB, but currently exceeds it.

I have link - https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#java

Config From Apache site

```
-Xmx6g -Xms6g -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M
-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
```

But I don't know how to configure it.

My goal is to setting a max memory limit value and Memory Value in Kubernetes Dashboard should not exceeds the max memory limit value.

**Note** -
Setting max memory limit value should not be in Kubernetes POD Level and its should be like setting value while Starting zookeeper,Kafka Server and kafka connect.

[image]

**-Xmx1G -Xms256M Proof**
[image]

Comment: The Kubernetes dashboard is showing the pod memory, not the JVM memory. Also 2G is fairly low for running a reasonable performing Kafka cluster

Comment: Yes 2G is Low and this is for testing purpose only. Then In Production env, its taking 30GB , so that i try to controlling it..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Image you are using for kafka you can supply these settings via the environment variable `KAFKA_OPTS`.

The documentation you are referring to is supplying these options to the call of *'java'*. Kafka, Zookeeper etc. are jars and there for stated via java.

Comment: Ok..I have given -Xmx1G and -Xms256M, But still kafka memory usage exceeds 1GB...I want to control it, but i cant.

Comment: Do you have proof that the settings are used ? Maybe a log?

Comment: I have added image in the question.

Comment: I have researched a bit and learned that the jvm can exceed -Xmx due to jvm-internal overhead. Here is another [question answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6527180/14435115) (look at the comments of this answer) which addresses this issue.

Comment: I have tried XX:MaxPermSize also, but in logs , this parametr is ignored..
Can we control it via kafka consumer,producer properties?

Comment: I don't think so because the consumer/producer does run in a different process. You only affect the broker indirectly by using them.